# React native android application has stopped

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I've stuck with an android version of an application (this one with "Welcome to React Native!" text). After this, I did exact steps as a documentation says. After build android version of this application, i copied signed version of APK file on my device and install it - when i'm trying to launch it then i receiving message "**Unfortunately, FirstProject has stopped**". Debug version of this application working fine. I've spent almost a week trying to run this, and i didn't find any solution. Do any one have any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem lies [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#enabling-proguard-to-reduce-the-size-of-the-apk-optional).
In the latest releases, pro guard is enabled by default. Try disabling it in android/app/build.gradle :

```
buildTypes {
  release {
      minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
  }
}
```

Change this :

```
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
```

to this :

```
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
```

Then run the steps again to create you APK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was a problem, and now it is working as it should.

Comment: i set def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false , but still got stopped immidiately => "unfortunately, app has stop"

any ideas?

Comment: sorry, that was associated with another issue, shouldn't connect to enableProguardInReleaseBuilds settings. thanks.

Comment: My projects enableProguardInReleaseBuilds default was false by default, but it still had a problem

Comment: **def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true**  is it still there or react native has removed that? As I can see if it's already there still the app size hasn't reduced

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's really not a lot of info to use.. but, if the difference is just debug ou signed, **I would search for obfuscation problems in the signed version**.

But this is just a wild guess. If you want to really get help you need to put the stack error here, as well as more info of the part of the code that crashes.