# Worked with app-release.apk,getting unfortunately app has stopped using react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

> Using react native i installed app-release.apk file suceessfully .But
>   when i open the app iam getting the message

```
'unfortunately <app name> has stopped'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406657/react-native-android-application-has-stopped/35413351#35413351)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies here. In the latest releases, pro guard is enabled by default. Try disabling it in android/app/build.gradle :

```
buildTypes {
  release {
      minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
  }
}
```

Change this :

```
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
```

to this :

```
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
```

Then run the steps again to create you APK.

Comment: Thankyou so much Hamaide.Now app open successfully after  modifying def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

Comment: didn't worked for me =( I'm using react-native 0.25.1