# Testing the generated signed Apk - react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to generate a signed apk of my first react native app I followed the steps in the [official site of react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content)

I tried this command `cd android && gradlew assembleRelease` and the apk is generated successfully.
[image]

but when I am trying to test this apk on my real device using `cd android && gradlew installRelease` , the app crashes although it works as expected on genymotion emulator.

Am I missing something ?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

**Update :**
I can't debug on my device because I am always getting the red screen says `Unable to download JS bundle` although I had done all what is mentioned on the official website about [running on the device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html)

logcat:

```
03-15 16:23:13.504 24331-24331/com.kora E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
03-15 16:23:13.939 24331-24359/com.kora E/unknown:React: Unable to download JS bundle


    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.6 (port 8081) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
                                                             at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
                                                             at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
                                                             at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform$Android.connectSocket(Platform.java:190)
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:196)
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245)
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267)
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.access$100(Call.java:34)
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:162)
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                          Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:208)
                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161) 
                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112) 
                                                             at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192) 
                                                             at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459) 
                                                             at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843) 
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform$Android.connectSocket(Platform.java:190) 
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:196) 
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172) 
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367) 
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128) 
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328) 
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245) 
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267) 
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224) 
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195) 
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.access$100(Call.java:34) 
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:162) 
                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33) 
                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
03-15 16:23:13.944 24331-24331/com.kora E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Comment: So you're able to launch the application on device but it crashed immediately? That sounds weird, especially if it works on emulator.

Comment: No, it does not sounds weird. Emulator is not an oracle. Check stacktrack of the crash

Comment: Yes, exactly. the app crashes even before the splash screen is displayed.

Comment: Any error log for crash?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Thanks for your reply, but How can I get the stacktrack, my app is not published yet? Is it something that I can get from my device ?

Comment: @AjayPandya I am testing the generated signed apk, so I have no log for crash

Comment: @NayraAhmed just run your app when i.e. ADB is connected to your device (i.e. when you got Android Studio running) and then look in Android Monitor (Logcat) tab

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski please see my update , I can't run the app on the device

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406657/react-native-android-application-has-stopped/35413351#35413351) : it might be related to you enabling Proguard :

Comment: @G.Hamaide , Thanks for your comment it helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @G. Hamaide for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35413351/1535314) , It worked for me but with a single addition in `buildTypes` in `app/build.gradle`, which is adding this line `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` as mentioned in the official documentation.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

That's plus what @G. Hamaide mentioned in his answer which is mentioned above.

> Change this :
>
> ```
> def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
> ```
>
> to this :
>
> ```
> def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
> ```
>
> Then run the steps again to create you APK.