# "Unfortunately, app has stopped" error with building React Native project on Android

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run a project written in React Native and the app crashes:

[image: Error image]

The solution stated on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406657/react-native-android-application-has-stopped) is irrelevant since the enableProguardInReleaseBuilds variable is already configured to false.

I've also had problems with RCT Video, solved with [this thread](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/217#issuecomment-237003002) so maybe it's related.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved after debugging in Android Studio.

The error I had (java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication) was solved with [greena13's answer on this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8215#issuecomment-231131762).

Comment: How do you debug this problem in Android Studio?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides run the app from Android studio and in the bottom left click on `logcat`

Comment: you can run app from Android Studio Terminal with `react-native run-android` and take a look to errors at Android Monitor

Comment: I've deleted the `build` folder under `android\app`. The red screen with the error appeared. In my case it's a NoClassDefFound

Answer (score 2):

When you encounter **Unfortunately, app has stopped** error and your app was crashed. You just need to debugging with `android studio` with following steps:

1. Open `command prompt` in root of the you react native app directory and run `react-native start`
2. Open your `android studio` software and click on `▶` (Shift + F10) button
3. And finally click on `logcat` button (in the bottom left) and see the reason for its crash

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you remove a class from your project but still refer to it within `AndroidManifest.xml`. Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` for any references to old libraries you have stripped out from your project.