# React-native example application has closed(Android)

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to run android application from react-native. I've tried standard application brought with "react-native init" and "Hello world" application from react-native github but I get this error stack on both emulator and device:

```
09-16 14:21:23.334  3441  3486 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
09-16 14:21:23.334  3441  3486 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.deleteme, PID: 3441
09-16 14:21:23.334  3441  3486 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
09-16 14:21:23.334  3441  3486 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1xStream.java:374)
09-16 14:21:23.334  3441  3486 E AndroidRuntime:    at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.java:993)
09-16 14:21:23.334  3441  3486 E AndroidRuntime:    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readByteArray(RealBufferedSource.java:106)
09-16 14:21:23.334  3441  3486 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.ResponseBody.bytes(ResponseBody.java:128)
09-16 14:21:23.334  3441  3486 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:154)
09-16 14:21:23.334  3441  3486 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevServerHelper$3.onResponse(DevServerHelper.java:301)
09-16 14:21:23.334  3441  3486 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:126)
09-16 14:21:23.334  3441  3486 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
09-16 14:21:23.334  3441  3486 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
09-16 14:21:23.334  3441  3486 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
09-16 14:21:23.334  3441  3486 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

And on device itself application tries to start, but crashes with message "Unfortunately, deleteme has stopped". According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406657/react-native-android-application-has-stopped) post I've checked enableProguardInReleaseBuilds in android/app/build.gradle and it was "false" by default. How can I make it work?